# Play! 2 Framework - Add Java Mongo driver

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, dependencies, mongo-java

I am trying to use the java mongo driver with Play!.

So I read though:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SBTDependencies

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial

I added the buildpath in eclipse. But play can't find the dependency.

So there is an example on the playframework homepage but I still can't figure it out.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(

      "org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3",
      "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3" % "test"

    )
```

Why are der two% signs? How do I get the correct names? I only know that the version should be 2.8.0.
So if I want to add the Java driver, what do I have to do?

And if i use the official java driver, I don't have to use Morphia right?

[Installing play framework mongodb morphia module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911698/installing-play-framework-mongodb-morphia-module)

.

.

Edit:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "website"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.8.0"
        //"com.mongodb" % "Mongo" %"2.8.0"

    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the MongoDB drivers to your Play project, edit your `project/Build.scala` file to add the MongoDB dependency:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(

   // ... here are your previous dependencies (derby etc...)
   "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.8.0"

)
```

After you add this, you need to restart your Play server for the changes to take affect.

Comment: Are you sure? I still get the same error. error: package com.mongodb does not exist ->  import com.mongodb.Mongo;

Comment: Okay nvm it worked. I just had to restart the server. But where did you get those names?

Comment: From a search in the central Maven repository: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmongo-java-driver

Comment: Does this driver is Reactive? Is it non-blocking?

Comment: @bashan this driver is blocking. If you want a Reactive one, take a look at http://reactivemongo.org/.

Comment: Thanks 
@nico_ekito. I don't understand what is the purpose of putting a blocking driver in a non-blocking framework.... :)

Comment: @bashan `mongo-java-driver` was built before Play :-)

Comment: Sure @nico_ekito, I meant that the default Mongo support on Play is for the blocking driver :)

Answer (score 1):

I use reactive-mongo for my project. You can find some information here
 http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10.5/documentation/tutorial/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

In case the accepted answer doesn't work for some of you , you can try adding this version of mongodb in the build.sbt

```
"org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "0.107"
```